# Can't install ubuntu on windows10 laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my windows10 MSI laptop. I've trying both usb and dvd drives to install it but every single time it stuck at the very beginning with the Ubuntu logo and five dots underneath. Could anyone help me with it please?

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: Yes, it is NVIDIA 960M graphic card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have NVIDIA graphics, there's an extra step you have to take before you can boot into the installer.

When GRUB comes up, highlight `Try Ubuntu` and press <kbd>E</kbd>. Put `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the line beginning with `linux` and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot into the Live Session.

Install Ubuntu and then check out [how you can get Ubuntu working after installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics).

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can start installing ubuntu. Also, many thanks for the link with instructions for problems after installing!

Comment: Sorry. It's my first time using this website and I didn't figure out how to accept your answer until now. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you  have installed Ubuntu but it's not working. If that's the case so: My laptop is HP Pavalion 15-AU003TX and I had the same problem too. If your system is **dual booted** (if you have installed Ubuntu alongside with your Windows 10) then:

### Step 1: Remove Ubuntu

1. Delete the **partition** in which you have installed your Ubuntu. Well it will not complete remove the Ubuntu from your system but it will delete most of the important files of the Ubuntu.
2. Then to remove the Ubuntu completely and safely from your system, remove it from **UEFI** through **cmd** (*run cmd as an administrator*) in Windows 10.
3. Here the link for [how to remove Ubuntu safely from UEFI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY). Just click on it for the tutorial.
4. Follow the steps as shown in the tutorial. And your Ubuntu is now finally removed.

### Step 2: Create an Unallocated partition

Now create a Unallocated partition for your Ubuntu through Disk Management Options.

### Step 3: Try to install Ubuntu again

Try to install Ubuntu again through any boot-able USB or DVD and follow these steps:

1. Plug/insert the boot-able media in your laptop and boot your system.
2. Open the **BIOS options** through pressing F10 key and turn on or enable the **Legacy Mode** from the the **boot options.** Well you can also through UEFI the choice is yours.
3. Save the settings and your Laptop will restart.
4. Now Press F9 during boot and the option for installing Ubuntu will appear on the screen.

> Note: There can be two options for installing Ubuntu through USB in Legacy Mode.

- Sandisk Cruzer Blade (UEFI)
- Sandisk Cruzer Blade

> > Choose first option if these same options appear on your screen.

5. After choosing your option, various option related Ubuntu will appear on the screen choose default. The test Ubuntu OS screen will open through which you can test Ubuntu.
6. Install Ubuntu through "**Install Ubuntu**" icon.
7. Choose your language and after that click on "Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows" option.

> After finishing the installation process your system will restart. Your **grub** will appear. Choose windows option from the grub if you want to check whether your Windows 10 is safe or not, otherwise you can choose Ubuntu.
>
> The loading screen will appear with Ubuntu logo and five dots. It might take some few minutes in loading (about 5 or more) so be patient. Also, if you are using boot-able USB then try to remove it before the grub repair after installation. If you failed to do so, then no problem just restart your pc and you will find your grub there.
>
> Well I think you know all these basic details so sorry writing such a long reply. I hope it will solve your problem and thank-you for reading.

Comment: You're suggesting switching to Legacy mode and then just booting in EFI mode after all. That doesn't change anything. While your answer is very nicely formatted, I'm not sure what it actually solves, since you're pretty much just saying "start over and try again."

Comment: Well my problem was solved by doing this so that why I shared it .  Actually I'm not sure too how it actually solved the problem but it worked for me. I'm also a rookie in using Ubuntu so I don't know the many details.

Comment: And one more thing, I said to choose the first option because when I chose the second option, my Linux installed successfully but it didn't installed the grub due to which I was not able to use Ubuntu in my system.